# Embeded Select: Concatenate Query in rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, powerbuilder

Can I somehow do this in mssql query alone, no SP or declares? Because I am going to embed this select in my Powerbuilder.

```
ID      text
1       a
1       b
1       c
2       a
2       d
3       e


into

ID      text
1       abc
2       ad
3       e
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood your question, but check out this [**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ef308/11):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   ID,
   (SELECT ''+text FROM Test WHERE ID=A.ID FOR XML PATH('')) AS text
FROM 
   Test A
```

Results:

```
ID  TEXT
1   abc
2   ad
3   e
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below Query

```
 SELECT
   ID, 
   text= 
   replace(
   STUFF((SELECT ','+text FROM test WHERE ID=A.ID FOR XML PATH('')) , 1 , 1 , '' )
   ,',','')
   FROM 
   test A group by ID
```

[SQLFiddle Demo here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ef1de/6)

Comment: The are no commas in sample output.